# Add new row to table

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
 HtmlTable baseCalendar = new HtmlTable();
 HtmlTableRow calendarRow = new HtmlTableRow();
 HtmlTableCell calendarCell = new HtmlTableCell();

 for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++)
 {
     calendarRow = new HtmlTableRow();

     for (int k = 0; k < 7; k++)
     {
         calendarCell = new HtmlTableCell();
         calendarRow.Cells.Add(calendarCell);
     }     

     baseCalendar.Rows.Add(calendarRow);                
 }
 //in this place how can add new row to first row of `baseCalendar`
```

for example :

```
 baseCalendar="
 <table>
   <tr id='row1'>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
 </table>"
```

how can add new row befor `row1`

Comment: Why are you creating a calendar by hand when there are controls that already do this?  Just curious.

Comment: @GodIsLive why do you want to add the top row at the end of all the processing?

Comment: also have a look at this:http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/PersianCalendarControl.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmltablerowcollection.insert%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) method, like this:

```
...
HtmlTableRow headers = new HtmlTableRow();
headers.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell("sat"));
...

baseCalendar.Rows.Insert(1, headers);
```